# SIlverlight concurrent connection limitation

Tags: silverlight-4.0, concurrency, asynchronous, connection, limit

I've built a Silverlight 4 application that loads a collection of images, and organizes the images into 'levels'. When the application loads, the default number of levels is 2, but the user is allowed to immediately request additional levels.

The problem is that due to the limitation on the number of concurrent requests, if the user attempts to request additional levels while the initial levels are still loading, their request gets 'queued' and they have to wait for all of the initial levels to complete loading before their request for aditional levels is handled.

My question is there any mechanism by which the queue of asynchronous requests, or information about the queue, can be accessed programtically from within Silverlight?

Comment: From everything I've seen, there is no way to access this information.